# ag-grid modify Row Group's Header name

Tags: react-redux, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using `ag-grid` to display a table which has a `Row Grouping`.
The column that I group by is invisible since its value holds no meaning.

So for example, I will have the following (*fully collapsed*) table:

```
---------------------------------
|   H1       H2        H3        |
----------------------------------
| > groupId1 (1)                 |
----------------------------------
| > groupId2 (5)                 |
----------------------------------
```

As you see the grouping is done by user-*un*friendly ID which is not reflected at all in the Column Definitions. I would like to change `groupId1` / `groupId2` to a user-friendly text that is assigned dynamically according to the content of the group rows.

I am using `React`.

I am using ag-Grids examples as a starting point, the following example embodies the problem I'm facing: (eg: https://plnkr.co/edit/VM59gScPD55PhX4y4JBj?p=preview)

1. It has row grouping
2. The grouping is done by a column that is invisible (country)
3. **I would like to change the country name dynamically into a different value that's derived from the values of the inner row.**

Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague helped me at the end, his solution was:

```
valueFormatter: ({ value, data }) => 'something ' + value
```

inside the colDef of my group, and the value to be displayed as the header is sent inside 'data'.

He said that cellRenderer is an overkill for a simple task like this.

Answer (score 6):

You can also rename the rowGroup header of ag-grid by using this simple prop 
**autoGroupColumnDef**

```
<AgGridReact 
  columnDefs={columnDefs} 
  rowData={rowData}
  autoGroupColumnDef={{
    headerName: 'Name'
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass additional params about group cell renderer and customize it like this -

```
colDef = {
    // set the cell renderer to 'group'
    cellRenderer:'agGroupCellRenderer',
    // provide extra params to the cellRenderer
    cellRendererParams: {
        innerRenderer: myInnerRenderer, // provide an inner renderer
    }
    ...
};
```

You should be then able to display any text based on custom logic using the `myInnerRenderer` implementation.

Here is an example from ag-grid [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/#example-group-cellrenderer). Check the  **Group Renderer C** implementation